# DllRegisterServer in MSCOMCT2.OCX failed

Tags: windows-xp-sp3, mscomct2.ocx

I tried to register MSCOMCT2.OCX at MS Win XP Prof 2002 SP 3. I got this error message - DllRegisterServer in MSCOMCT2.OCX failed. I checked it under C:\WINDOWS\system32. It's already there. But still got this error.